# list of css3 properties with their javascript counterpart

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing an little application that uses css3 tranforms. I would like to set the values for transformations directly via javascript, using the element.style property. Based on the code i found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml) i would like to know where i can find a list that shows how to name css3 properties as javascript property. f.e.:
-moz-box-shadow becomes MozBoxShadow. May be this list does not exist because I just have to exchange all hyphens by their following letter in upper case, but i would like to be sure that this is the case.
Does anybody know??

EDIT::

So just because i needed any kind of working solution i wrote this little function which works in ie9, ff, safari and chrome:

```
var cssprops = (function(){

    var prefixes = [ "", "-ms-", "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-o-" ];
    var properties = [ "transform", "transform-origin" ];
    var finder = /-(\w)/ig;
    var str, pre, result;
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var result = {};

    for( var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ){
        pre = prefixes[ i ];
        for( var j = 0; j < properties.length; j++ ){
            if( $.browser.msie ){
                str = pre.replace( /-/i, "" );
                str += properties[ j ]; 
            } else {
                str = pre + properties[ j ];
            }

            str = str.replace( finder, function( w ){
                return w.replace( /-/i, "" ).toUpperCase();
            });

            if( typeof root.style[ str ] !== "undefined" &&
                !result.hasOwnProperty( properties[ j ] ) ){
                result[ properties[ j ] ] = str;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
})();
```

I have not tried any other properties because i do not need them this time, but if it turns out that this will work for the whole list i would be happy to be notified about it.

Greetings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are vendor prefixes for CSS properties, the abuse of vendor prefixes is a bad practice and it's not recommended. If you wanna know why here is a [post explaining it](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/03/css_vendor_pref.html). Also, [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml) is what you are looking for with a [list](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) for the prefixes.